# Reuse existing Django rest framework serializer

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am currently using Django Rest Framework and I am looking for a way to reuse some attributes from an already defined Serializer. In order to explain, I am going to expose some of the serializers involved:

Completed Serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subscribed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    other_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'subscribed',
            'other_field',
            'x',
            'y',
            'z'
        ]

    def get_subscribed(self, product: Product):
        return product.is_user_subscribed(self.context['request'].user)
```

Simplified Serializer:

```
class ProductSimplifiedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subscribed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'subscribed'
        ]

    def get_subscribed(self, product: Product):
        return product.is_user_subscribed(self.context['request'].user)
```

As you can notice above, those serializers are almost the same, but one of them is a simplified version of the object because I don't want to retrieve unnecessary information in some parts. The problem here is that in this scenario we have a method serializer that will need to be maintained two times. Maybe in the future, I would want to add another field, and I will need to add it to both. So, how could be achieved a Based Serializer in which all the fields are included but I could reuse it and extract specific fields from it?

I have already thought these options:
1. Using Base Serializer instance:
Draft:

```
def to_representation(self, instance)
    desired_format = self.context['format']
    if desired_format == 'simplified':
        fields = ['fields_for_simplified']
    elif desired_format == 'regular':
        fields = ['fields_for_regular']

    for field in fields:
        # make the representation
```

With this approach, I do not know even if it would be a good idea or it is possible

2. Using SerializerField
   Draft:

```
class UserSubscribed(serializer.SerializerField)
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return 'representation'

class ProductSimplifiedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_subscribed = UserSubscribed()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'user_subscribed'
        ]
```

I think this last one is better, the problem is that this _user_subscribed_ is not a property of the Product instance and it is failing because of that and I do not know how to achieve this.

What would be your suggestion regarding this situation? Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass the simple one and add fields in the full one.

```py
class ProductSimplifiedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subscribed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'subscribed'
        ]

    def get_subscribed(self, product: Product):
        return product.is_user_subscribed(self.context['request'].user)


class ProductSerializer(ProductSimplifiedSerializer):
    other_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta(ProductSimplifiedSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ProductSimplifiedSerializer.Meta.fields + [
            'other_field',
            'x',
            'y',
            'z'
        ]
```

The trick here is that you can subclass the `Meta` class too. Any attributes you define in the Meta subclass will overwrite the parent ones, so you gotta manually use the parent ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can create mixin for serializer class which would let you specify which fields will be "used" in serializer, any else will be ignored.

```
class DynamicFieldsMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

Then you can use your serializer like this:

```
class ProductSerializer(DynamicFieldsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer)

serializer = ProductSerializer(fields=("id", "name", "subscribed"))
```